Convert Ollama's Structured Output from JSON to Python DF
I'm having a devil of a time converting structured output from Ollama's new API to a df.  The following is JSON output from the Data Extraction example on the Ollama page on structured outputs (https://ollama.com/blog/structured-outputs):
pets=[
  Pet(name='Luna', animal='cat', age=5, color='grey', favorite_toy='yarn'), 
  Pet(name='Loki', animal='cat', age=2, color='black', favorite_toy='tennis balls')
]

After trying several different python-based JSON conversion modules without success, I tried replacing the parentheses with braces and to remove all instances of "Pet", but none of the replace functions work with this structure.  Any help is appreciated.

That's not JSON and no JSON parser will know what to do with it. It seems like you've used ollama to convert JSON to python, but in your case, that's not what you want. In the page you reference, there is an example country = Country.model_validate_json(response.message.content). Likely, response.message.json is what you want.

Thanks for your reply and suggestion.  The "json" extension is deprecated.  Instead, it's
country = Country.model_validate_json(response.message.model_json_schema), which throws an error: JSON input should be string, bytes or bytearray

Actually, the json is created in the function with Petlist.model_json_schema. Printing the output (response.message.content) produces the following, which seems like JSON: {"pets": [     {         "name": "Luna",         "animal": "cat",         "age": 5,         "color": "grey",         "favorite_toy": "yarn"     },     {         "name": "Loki",         "animal": "cat",         "age": 2,         "color": "black",         "favorite_toy": "tennis balls"     } ]}

Well, it took a while but here's what worked. I had to spend some quality time learning more about JSON nested objects and how to process them.  I found this website particularly helpful. The code is:

temp = json.loads(response.message.content)

df = pd.json_normalize(temp['pets'])


Here's the output as a pandas df:

   name animal  age  color  favorite_toy
0  Luna    cat    5   grey          yarn
1  Loki    cat    2  black  tennis balls

